# How to overwrite a specific line in a file [C]

Tags: c

File data example line:

```
Sicilia 005 frenkco mastro 202020kkk 3 11-23-2155 12-44-6666
```

I want to overwrite that line with another same line copied but with some changed values:

```
Calabria 006 frenkco mastro 202020kkk 3 11-23-2155 12-44-6666
```

That's the result i want, but if I change values and then use "fprintf", it prints a new line without deleting the first one.

Comment: You could seek the file to the start of the old line and then fprintf, but that would only work if the new line is the same length as the old one; otherwise you'll have to move all of the data afterwards backwards or forwards by a few bytes in the file to adjust. If the file is small it might be easier to read it all in and write it all out again after any changes, or at least everything from the line that you've changed; if the file is large then it might be better to use a simple database instead e.g. sqlite.

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overwrite a specific line, because lines are just *conventions* related to `\n` bytes. Please read more about [C programming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and consider reading the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) C standard.

You either want to *copy* the source file to a target one (this is how [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) works on Linux; study [its](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) source code since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)) or use higher-level approaches such as [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or databases.

For small amount of data practically fitting in RAM (e.g. less than a gigabyte) or in your [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), a common approach is to generate a new textual file entirely. It might be a temporary file that you'll rename (e.g. using [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) or simply later on)

You could want to read a textbook on [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and/or learn to use [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) (perhaps [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) or [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/), but there are many other approaches too) or [indexed files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_file).

In some cases, you might consider [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, perhaps using textual formats like [JSON](https://json.org/) or [YAML](https://yaml.org/) (for which many [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) libraries are available, and worth studying).